# IBM Cloud Functions / OpenWhisk Slack package and message attachments

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, slack, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am trying to use the Slack package available for [IBM Cloud Functions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_slack.html#openwhisk_catalog_slack) and [OpenWhisk](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-catalog/tree/master/packages/slack). I created a Node.js action that produces a JSON object with **text** and **attachments** values. The object is passed along in a sequence that uses the post method of the Slack package. The message itself is shown when posted via Incoming Webhook, the attachment is not. Why? What needs to be changed?

```
return {text : "regular message text", attachments: [
       { fallback: "my fallback message",
         title: "some nice title",
         mrkdwn_in: ["text"],
         text : "Simple text"}
        ]};
```

The action sequence is created this way, webhook and username are bound following the steps in the documentation:

```
ibmcloud fn action update mySequence --sequence myAction,mySlack/post
```

I checked the [source code for the post action](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-catalog/blob/master/packages/slack/post.js) and it stringifies the attachments array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing it on my own for a [Cloud Functions action that posts statistics](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/slack/postWeeklyStats.js).

```
// now compose the payload and post it to Slack
 var payload= {
    text : resString,
    channel : channel,
    attachments: [
       {
         fallback: "Weekly top 25 repositories",
         title: "Top 25 repositories by unique views ("+workweek+")",
         mrkdwn_in: ["text"],
         text : dataString
        }
        ]
      };

 var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: webhook,
  body: payload,
  resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};

// return response to the request, so the status will be logged
return rp(options).then(function(response) {
  return response;
});
```

Straight forward and works well since weeks.